# How can I pass non-string values to Angular directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, type-conversion, angular-directive

I have a custom angular directive that graphically represents an “activity” in my webapp. I use it like this:

```
<activity-box ng-repeat="act in activities"
    model="act" active="{{currentActivity == act}}" />
```

My directive has an isolated scope and declares `model` and `active` like this:

```
appDirectives.directive('activityBox', function() {
    return {
        template: '<div ng-class="{activityActive: active == \'true\'}">{{model.name}}</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            active: '@'
        },
        link: ...
    };
});
```

I have no worry about the `model` attribute, but my `active` attribute is always treated as a string. When `currentActivity == act` is true, then `active` holds the string value `"true"` (and not the boolean `true`), or else, `"false"` (and not `false`).

This means that although it conceptually is a boolean, I must treat it as a string. For instance, I'd like to write `ng-class="{activityActive: active}"` instead `ng-class="{activityActive: active == 'true'}"`. Right now, if I forget the extra part, this always evaluate to true, as both `"false"` and `"true"` are truthy.

Is there any way for me to obtain non-string attributes like this? What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: When you pass the argument with `@` it is always treated as a string (in your case it is interpolated first though). If you want the value of an expression you should go with `=`. [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/7q5w6bYlwzrC80ht4eGK?p=preview) that demonstrates it.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Thanks a lot — I hadn't realised I could also use full expressions (even non-assignable ones) in an attribute mapped with `'='`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about?

```
<activity-box ng-repeat="act in activities"
    model="act" active="currentActivity == act" />

scope: {
            model: '=',
            active: '='
        },
```

Just tried - it works. And has binding, so if 'currentActivity' or 'act' would change, value of 'active' inside directive would also change.

Comment: Thanks a lot — for debugging purposes, I had bound `active` to an `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="active">` in my template, and this was (understandably) throwing a `noassign` exception when I clicked the checkbox. I though this was thrown at compile time and had given up on that solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As the code is shown above the directive is not associated to your tag.

By default directives are restricted to attributes only, and you are attempting to use it as an element.

In your directive add this line:

```
replace: true,
restrict: 'E', // <--- This line
scope: {
```

**EDIT**
You can accept in the active flag by linking it to the parent scope using `=` when defining your scope, but changing it in your directive changes it in your controller's scope

```
active="currentActivity == act"
scope: { active: '=' }
```

But you can accept it via a string and parse it in your controller using the `$parse` service:

```
active="{{currentActivity == act}}"
scope: { active: '@' }
link: function(scope){
    var booleanValue = $parse(scope.active)();
}
```

Comment: Actually I did have `restrict: 'E'` in my code, but accidentally omitted it in my question when I copy-pasted. Your answer does not address the string-vs-boolean problem.

Comment: You are correct, but what you had above is a workable solution even though you desired a different means of getting there. I tried to explain different ways you can reference the parent scope in your directive in my updated answer, hopefully that clarifies the differences between `=` and `@`

Comment: If I use `$parse`, though, it means `booleanValue` won't be automatically updated when the model changes, right? I'd have to `$watch` the attribute.

Comment: You are correct, except you'd have to use `&` which allows you to just look into the referencing controller's scope. see this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ae9QlfM1aT8929fiaOPr?p=preview

Comment: Interesting. Would it have been wrong to use `scope.$parent.$eval(scope.active)` instead of `$parse(scope.active)()`?

Comment: Yes, while the directive's scope is a child of the controller's scope it would make the directive tired to a specific implementation in the controller. This would also impact the testability of the directive.

Comment: But actually, `$parse(scope.active)()` requests a scope as an argument, so I'd have to use `$parse(scope.active)(scope.$parent)`, and we have the same problem. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe you are missing something, the `scope` argument into your link function is different than the `$scope` that you inject into your controllers, check out this video which does a good job of explaining the differences https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-function-scope-and-scope

Comment: Yes, but the function that `$parse` returns needs a context object (usually a scope) to be evaluated in. Which one would it be in your example?